# Fedora, httpd and different versions

Tags: apache-httpd

I have two servers with Fedora 35 and the same httpd version

```
machine 1> rpm -q httpd
httpd-2.4.51-2.fc35.x86_64
```

and

```
machine 2> rpm -q httpd
httpd-2.4.51-2.fc35.x86_64
```

When I check the version with nmap (`nmap -sV -p 443 --script ssl-enum-ciphers hostname`) I get two different results:

- machine1: `|_http-server-header: Apache/2.4.51 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.1.1l`
- machine2: `|_http-server-header: Apache/2.4.51 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.1.1l SVN/1.14.1`

Where does the `SVN/1.14.1` come from? What is influencing the header?

Answer (score 1):

`machine2` had `mod_dav_svn` installed.